# Flex HTTPService in Flash

Tags: apache-flex, flash, httpservice

Is there a standard equivalent to the Flex HTTPService class in Flash CS4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take advantage of classes from Flex in Flash CS4, by adding a reference to the flex libraries as explain [in this blog](http://flashauthoring.blogspot.com/2008/10/using-flex-webservice-component-in.html).
The example uses the Web Service component, but you can use the HttpService similarly.

Answer (score 2):

yes but you have to do it manually , you have to choice , urlloader combined with urlrequest for example :

```
var urlloader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
urlloader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE , completeFunction );
urlloader.load(new URLRequest("http://......"));


function completeFunction(e:Event):void
{
  // do what you want with the result   
  e.currentTarget.data

}
```

or just include the flex.swc in you lib folder with flash CS and use the HTTspervice

Comment: Yes, but this new answer is a more thorough answer that adds helpful information (despite the sloppy writing).